# how to change the shape of an object to follow the shape of another object without changing the pattern of the first object?

Tags: modifiers, objects

[image: Object]

I have two objects. The first object is the red rectangle with pattern, and the second is triangle. The red one is a tiles roof. I used array and solidify to make it. I want to change the shape of my roof according to the triangle one. I only know to cut it using knife. But I want to make the change automatically. How to do that?

Comment: This looks as though, (at least for long-shots), it could be a bump or displacement texture instead of geometry? You could bake your own height-map from your array...

Comment: How are the tiles supposed to end in the oblique parts? Being cut or plain tiles (crenelated)?